# How to set an environmental variable in Apache (or OS) and get the value in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I made sure the env module was installed:

```
a2enmod
Your choices are: access_compat
...
Which module(s) do you want to enable (wildcards ok)?
env
Module env already enabled
```

I tried setting an environmental variable in "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" for localhost by adding the following section:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin me@somewhere.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SetEnv devmode 1
</VirtualHost>
```

...restarted Apache using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

...and then getting the value in PHP using:

```
getenv("devmode")
```

or:

```
apache_getenv("devmode")
```

...but nothing shows up with these functions when accessing the script via a browser on localhost, the values are empty in PHP.  I tried placing the command on it's own, without the VirtualHost section:

```
SetEnv devmode 1
```

I tried adding the following line to envvars:

```
export devmode=1
```

**Update**
I also tried putting the VirtualHost section in a dedicated file in /etc/apache2/sites-available, and adding the file with a2ensite.

I am using Linux Mint version 17.3.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that the virthost directive was executed. Apache won't apply ALL vhosts, just the first one it finds that matches.

Comment: I'm not sure about Apache at all.  Though there is no other "VirtualHost" section in the apache2.conf file.

Comment: Try putting the SetEnv devmode test to your .htaccess file

Comment: Where is .htaccess and what is the syntax?

Comment: Are you even using virtual hosts in the first place? If you aren't, just place `SetEnv devmode 1` anywhere (without a `<VirtualHost>` container).

Comment: I tried that, also did not work for me.  I updated my question.

Comment: I have the impression you're still not sure of what virtual hosts are or which one your site is hosted at. Do you load the site as `http://localhost` or via an IP address or registered domain name? Do you have a non-default port?

Comment: I am accessing localhost, I didn't change the default port number.  I updated my question.

Comment: this may be obvious....but did you test that you were editing the right apache2.conf?

Comment: I tried without the port number and I got a syntax error running "apache2ctl configtest".  So I guess this is the right apache2.conf file.  It is in /etc/apache2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting the VirtualHost section into a dedicated file, as I described in the original question, I found that the solution was to run the Apache restart command again:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then the devmode variable showed up in PHP.

Comment: Do you mean that running `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` once didn't work?

Comment: No, I did this after creating the dedicated file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [apache_getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php) ?

Comment: OK, that is useful to know about.  I tried this change though and the value from apache_getenv("devmode") is false.

Comment: In my experience, environment variables show up everywhere (`getenv()`, `$_ENV`, `$_SERVER`...). There's normally no need for a dedicated Apache function.

Comment: Álvaro González Do you mean apache_getenv is a dedicated function?

Comment: @tyebillion To be honest I haven't tried it and I don't even know what it does. But I only meant that environmental variables created with Apache's `SetEnv` directive are simply merged with the rest and you don't need a function specifically designed to grab them.